# html-pdf generating broken pdf

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, html-pdf

I am using html-pdf in nodejs cloud functions for generating pdf. The package is working properly when I am running the cloud functions locally. After deploying the cloud functions in firebase cloud function for generating pdf is generating broken pdf file.

Comment: Can you attach your code (and screenshot of issue if possible) which may help to find out root cause?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution

##### Just add the code below to options

> `childProcessOptions: { env: { OPENSSL_CONF: '/dev/null' }`

so it will look like this

```
pdf.create(html, {/* ... */ childProcessOptions: { env: { OPENSSL_CONF: '/dev/null' }}).toFile(`./public/invoices/${order.id}.pdf`, (err, res) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
    });
```

then it will work perfectly